# Reading from StreamReader while also being fed events python asnycio

Tags: python, python-3.x, events, stream, python-asyncio

I am very new to this area of python so keep that in mind.

I have a StreamReader named sock_reader and to read data from it, I use this:

`data = yield from self.sock_reader.read(1024)`

Separate from that, I also need to handle events whenever data is received. I achieve that like this:

`self.sock_reader.feed_data = self.on_data`

```
def on_data(self, data):
    code, length = struct.unpack('<ii', data[:8])
    payload = json.loads(data[8:].decode('utf-8'))
```

The problem is, whenever I try and use that event receiving system, the other method of reading no longer works. It just doesn't read anything. Is there any way to fix this? Pardon me if I sound like I don't know what I'm talking about because I pretty much don't.

Answer (score 0):

Wow, I sure am dumb. I just realized that by setting the new feed_data, I was probably overwriting what was used to pass the data to the read function.